# Saving part of a larger fillable pdf file as a smaller fillable pdf file for adobe reader

Tags: adobe-reader

I have a PDF document that is around 600 pages.  I only need to use roughly 20 pages total from the document.

**Is there a way to save those pages that I need into a separate PDF while still keeping them fillable?**

I only have Adobe Reader and would rather not pay for a program to do this for me.

Answer (score 0):

I believe an application called PDFsam might be what you are looking for - it's open source and free and is designed to both split and merge PDFs. [PDFsam.org](http://www.pdfsam.org/?page_id=32)

Comment: Thank you for the help. I downloaded the application, but when I add my file to be split, it says that there are 0 pages. Is there a help section for this?